# Fragments and Activity Method Architecture

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am not sure how to word this question but I have a situation where I have a few fragments all linked to one Activity.

Situation:

- The user clicks a button in fragment A, a call back is sent to the Activity with a string.
- The Activity gets the content of another Fragment B (other primitives), there are two ways of going about the next option

  A) The Activity creates the desired TextView and passes it (TextView) and the primitives of Fragment B to Fragment C

  B) The Activity just passes the string and other primitives to Fragment C for it to create the TextView within itself.

So my question would be along the lines of where should I keep *key* code at? Would it be better to have callbacks to the Activity and have it create custom TextViews when needed or just pass objects to fragments and let that fragment create TextViews. My current method is going with option A above but it seems pointless when I am loading from a saved state (say when the screen rotates) to instead just load everything locally within that fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really easy to mix up your view code with a lot of other code in your activities and fragments with Android. There are not clear levels of separation and your view and controller code often gets jumbled together.

For this reason, it is usually best to create a plan and stick with it. In your case it seems like it would be best to handle all your view code within each fragment. So I think it would be good to avoid having the activity create any TextViews. This way the fragments can each be in charge of their individual UIs without the Activity having to worry about it.

So I would say avoid option A, and go with option B.